# Pass RR in BLE Protocol [Heart Rate] for Arduino

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino

**code:**

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>



byte flags = 0b00011110;
byte bpm;
byte rr;
byte heart[8] = { 0b00011110, 60, 60, 60, 60 , 60, 60, 60};
byte hrmPos[1] = {2};

bool _BLEClientConnected = false;

#define heartRateService BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x180D)
BLECharacteristic heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A37), BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLECharacteristic sensorPositionCharacteristic(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A38), BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ);
BLEDescriptor heartRateDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));
BLEDescriptor sensorPositionDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      _BLEClientConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      _BLEClientConnected = false;
    }
};

void InitBLE() {
  BLEDevice::init("Sensor X");
  // Create the BLE Server
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pHeart = pServer->createService(heartRateService);

  pHeart->addCharacteristic(&heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics);
  heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics.addDescriptor(&heartRateDescriptor);
  heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics.addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  pHeart->addCharacteristic(&sensorPositionCharacteristic);
  sensorPositionCharacteristic.addDescriptor(&sensorPositionDescriptor);

  pServer->getAdvertising()->addServiceUUID(heartRateService);

  pHeart->start();
  // Start advertising
  pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start");
  InitBLE();
  bpm = 1;
  rr = 800;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  heart[1] = (byte)bpm;
  int energyUsed = 3000;
  heart[3] = energyUsed / 256;
  heart[6] = (byte)bpm;
  heart[2] = energyUsed - (heart[2] * 256);
  Serial.println(bpm);
  Serial.println(rr);

  heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics.setValue(heart, 8);
  heartRateMeasurementCharacteristics.notify();

  sensorPositionCharacteristic.setValue(hrmPos, 1);
  rr++;
  bpm++;
  delay(2000);
}
```

I have the above code - and I have been looking at this [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/blecharacteristic) but I can't figure out how do I pass the `RR` data over `BLE`. I set the flags according to the `BLE` spec shown [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml). But whenever I use an app to see the data "HRV Logger", it says that I am not transmitted RR data. I thought all I had to do was pass heart[6] data and that would show up as `RR`. I have dummy information being passed since I'm not connected to any sensors. Help would be helpful, determining how to pass the `RR` data across, thanks! (for future reference I am using the `Sparkfun ESP32`, but this shouldn't affect solving the issue since it has to do with protocols)